# ssrs reportviewer loading to infinity without error message

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, reportviewer, reporting-services

when i run a report **with parameter** in my asp.net application i see **loading div to infinity**
without any indication of an error *(so i dont know how to search about this issue in google)*

**note1:**
i can run the same report directly from report server

**note2:**
if i removed the parameter it run normally from asp.net page as well as from report server

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            oID = (Int64)Session["OID"];
            ViewReport();
        }


    public void ViewReport()
    {
        string reportServerUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("ReportServerPath");
        ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new System.Uri(reportServerUrl);
        ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"/StoReports/MyReport";

        ReportViewer.ServerReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("OID", oID.ToString()));
        ReportViewer.ServerReport.Refresh();
    }
```

in a function called Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data)

**tools** sql server Denali , visual studio 2010

Comment: Do you see any errors in the javascript console
?

Comment: @jrummell **"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0"**
*in a function called* *Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_endPostBack(error, executor, data)* 
**Good guess**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[this article explains the issue in details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brianhartman/archive/2010/03/21/reports-never-stop-loading-with-vs-2010.aspx)

> > 1-Browser makes a GET request to the ASPX page to get the page content
> >     and a loading indicator for the report.
> >
> > 2-Browser makes a POST request
> >     to the ASPX page to get the HTML for the report (this content is in an
> >     UpdatePanel).
> >
> > 3-Browser makes GET requests to the HTTP handler to get
> >     all the images in the report In step 2 the request to get the report
> >     content runs the ASP.Net page, including any code you have placed in
> >     the page.
> >
> > Why does this matter? code was added to the load event of the page
> >     that altered the state of the report viewer.   The most common example
> >     I’ve seen is user code calling SetParameters in the load event, though
> >     there are several methods and properties that will trigger this. 
> >     Changing the parameter values tells the ReportViewer that it needs to
> >     restart report processing.  Effectively, it tells the viewer to return
> >     to step 1 – put the loading indicator in the browser and restart
> >     report processing.  If you do this during every postback, the viewer
> >     never successfully completes step 2.  It just goes into an infinite
> >     loop.
> >
> > Calling methods like SetParameters isn’t cheap.  Each call triggers a
> >     round trip to the report server.  So it’s a call you want to minimize
> >     anyway.  By only calling SetParameters during the initial GET request
> >     or only when parameter values have actually changed, you can improve
> >     the performance of your application and break the loop.  A simple
> >     check of IsPostBack before calling SetParameters is usually
> >     sufficient.